# Compute $\pi_k(T^n, T^{n-1})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Here $T^n=(S^1)^n$ is the real torus. I would like to compute $\pi_k(T^n, T^{n-1})$ for at least $k=1,2$.

For clarity, we can think of $T^{n-1}$ as the subset $T^{n-1}\times \{x_0\}\subset T^n$ for some fixed point $x_0\in S^1$.

Comment: Read up on the exact sequence of relative homotopy groups, which Wikipedia calls the Puppe sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inclusion $T^{n-1}\hookrightarrow T^n$ has a retraction given by the projection $\pi:T^n\rightarrow T^{n-1}$. Thus the homomorphisms $\pi_kT^{n-1}\rightarrow \pi_kT^n$ which are induced by the inclusion are split monic and the long exact sequence of the pair $(T^n,T^{n-1})$ splits up to give isomorphisms
$$\pi_kT^n\cong \pi_kT^{n-1}\oplus\pi_k(T^n,T^{n-1}),\qquad \forall k\geq1.$$
Now using the isomorphism $\pi_k(X\times Y)\cong \pi_kX\times\pi_kY$, which holds for any spaces $X,Y$, we have by induction that
$$\pi_kT^n=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}^n&k=1\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Thus we conclude that
$$\pi_k(T^n,T^{n-1})=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&k=1\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Note that in this case $\pi_1(T^n,T^{n-1})$ has a group structure, since $T^n,T^{n-1}$ are topological groups and the inclusion $T^{n-1}\hookrightarrow T^n$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. I have a stupid question. Do we need to assume $n\ge 2$? What if $n=1$?

Comment: Presumably you set $T^0=\ast$. Then $\pi_kT^1\xrightarrow\cong\pi_k(T^1,\ast)$ is an isomorphism for each $k\geq1$.